# Encode / decode JSON "string" in kotlinx.serialization

Tags: json, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

Is it possible to encode / decode any valid json objects in string format in a custom serializer.
For example the code below but not let it serialize as json string but as any valid JSON with unknown structure?

```kotlin
object JsonObjectSerializer : KSerializer<JsonObject> {

    override val descriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("JsonObject", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): JsonObject =
        JsonObject(decoder.decodeString())

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: JsonObject): Unit =
        encoder.encodeString(value.encode())
}
```

Out would be something like..

```json
{
    "some": "data",
    "jsonObject": "{\"this\": \"should not be a string\"}"
}
```

But wanted output would be..

```json
{
    "some": "data",
    "jsonObject": {"this": "should not be a string"}
}
```

Comment: Have you found any solutions to this? It seems like Jackson provides this (at least in the serialization side) through the `@JsonRawValue` annotation, but I can't seem to find the same in `kotlinx.serialization`.

Comment: @MichelePalmia yes it's possible to use JsonElement as serializable value https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#json-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`encoder.encodeJsonElement`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx.serialization.json/-json-encoder/encode-json-element.html) might do what you want.

I use `encodeJsonElement` myself in the implementation of [`UnknownPolymorphicSerializer<P, W>`](https://github.com/cph-cachet/carp.core-kotlin/blob/develop/carp.common/src/commonMain/kotlin/dk/cachet/carp/common/infrastructure/serialization/UnknownPolymorphicSerializer.kt)

> A serializer for polymorph objects of type [P] which wraps extending types unknown at runtime as instances of type [W].

I extract the known structure and wrap the the unknown structure. Maybe a similar use case than you are after? The specifics, and use case, are fairly complicated, but documented in "[UnknownPolymorphicSerializer: (De)serializing unknown types](https://github.com/cph-cachet/carp.core-kotlin/blob/develop/docs/serialization.md#unknownpolymorphicserializer-deserializing-unknown-types)".

```
@InternalSerializationApi
override fun serialize( encoder: Encoder, value: P )
{
    // This serializer assumes JSON serialization with class discriminator configured for polymorphism.
    // TODO: It should also be possible to support array polymorphism, but that is not a priority now.
    if ( encoder !is JsonEncoder )
    {
        throw unsupportedException
    }
    getClassDiscriminator( encoder.json ) // Throws error in case array polymorphism is used.

    // Get the unknown JSON object.
    check( value is UnknownPolymorphicWrapper )
    val unknown = Json.parseToJsonElement( value.jsonSource ) as JsonObject

    // HACK: Modify kotlinx.serialization internals to ensure the encoder is not in polymorphic mode.
    //  Otherwise, `encoder.encodeJsonElement` encodes type information, but this is already represented in the wrapped unknown object.
    AccessInternals.setField( encoder, "writePolymorphic", false )

    // Output the originally wrapped JSON.
    encoder.encodeJsonElement( unknown )
}
```

P.s. `AccessInternals` is an expected implementation of mine to be able to use kotlin reflect, not supported on JS, since this is a multiplatform library.